# How To Center Text Using FlexLayout

Tags: angular

I am working on a responsive navigation component. I am able to right align links but unable to center "BuySell" text in the component. Here is the HTML code.

```
<div class="app-container">
   <mat-toolbar  color="white"
       fxLayoutGap="8px"  
       class="app-toolbar" >  
       <div fxHide.gt-xs>
        <button mat-icon-button (click)="onToggleSidenav()">
            <mat-icon>menu</mat-icon>
        </button>
       </div>
       <div class="icon-center" fxLayout fxLayoutAlign="center">
        BuySell
       </div>
            <div fxFlex fxLayout fxLayoutAlign="end" fxHide.xs>
                <ul fxLayout fxLayoutGap="15px" class="navigation-items">
                    <li>
                        <a routerLink="/home">Home</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a routerLink="/auth">Log In</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
         </div>
        <ng-template #logOut>
        <div >
            <button class="button--text-only" (click)=onLogOut()  
               routerLink="home">Log Out</button>
         </div>
        </ng-template>
    </mat-toolbar>
</div>
```

Here is a [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-sse4n5-4c9zqu)

Comment: Check I have updated the `stackblitz`. If this isn't the way how you want let me know.
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-sse4n5-g6tdyi?file=app/nav/nav.component.html

Answer (score 0):

Try like this,

```
<div class="icon-center" fxLayout="column" fxLayoutAlign="center center" fxFlex>
        BuySell
</div>
```

[STACKBLITZ DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-sse4n5-tautah?file=app/nav/nav.component.html)